# I truly want to find a method/strategy/trick which can be used for all kinda mixture problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If we put $40gr$ of water, $20gr$ of salt into the $40gr$ of
>   water-salt mixture that has $\%60$ of salt, Find the percent of salt in the new mixture.

I truly want to find a method/strategy/trick which can be used for all kinda mixture problems. I've tried drawing a diagram as well  didn't work. Instead of solving this problem, I'd like know a trick.

Regards!

Comment: Can anyone share any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to construct a table with the amount of salt and the amount of water in the new mixture?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig No, I haven't because I don't know how to.

Comment: Why downvote? Is it bad to ask something?

Comment: In the $40$gr water-salt mixture, what is the number of grams of salt present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find it helpful to place the data in a table.

We know that the first solution has $40~\text{g}$ of water and $0~\text{g}$ of salt and that the second solution has $0~\text{g}$ of water and $20~\text{g}$ of salt.  The third solution is a $40~\text{g}$ solution that is $60\%$ salt.  The amount of salt in that solution is
$$40~\text{g} \cdot \frac{60}{100} = 24~\text{g}$$
so the remaining $(40 - 24)~\text{g} = 16~\text{g}$ of that solution is water.  Putting the above information into a table gives:

$$
\begin{array}{l c c c}
\text{mixture} & \text{water (g)} & \text{salt (g)} & \text{total (g)}\\ \hline
\text{solution 1} & 40 & 0 & 40\\
\text{solution 2} & 0 & 20 & 20\\
\text{solution 3} & 16 & 24 & 40\\ \hline
\text{new mixture} & 56 & 44 & 100
\end{array}
$$

You can obtain the percentage of the salt in the new mixture by dividing the grams of salt in the new mixture by the total number of grams in the solution and multiplying by $100\%$.  In this case, that is easy since there are a total of $100~\text{g}$ of the new mixture.
$$\frac{44~\text{g}}{100~\text{g}} \cdot 100\% = 44\%$$

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Can I use this method for all problems?

Comment: You can always set up a table.  However, you may have to first calculate the number of grams of salt (or whatever else is dissolved in solution) for each of the given solutions before you place the entries in the table, as I did with the third solution.  What I did was essentially what Ross Millikan suggested.  I put the information in a table to make it easier for you to understand.  Try this method on some more problems.  If you encounter difficulties, ask another question.  Make sure you show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck to prevent the question from being closed.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to read the problem and compute the total water and salt in the final mix.  You have $40$g of mix that is $60\%$ salt, so the mix has $24$g of salt and $16$g of water.  Add that to the first two and take the ratio.

Comment: I didn't get what you actually mean.

Comment: Do you see how much water and salt is in the $40$g mix?

Comment: I do but I wanted to solve it with diagram.

Comment: I don't know what diagram you would draw.

Comment: How can i draw the correct diagram?